# Failed to run `/usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 450.80.02 -k 5.4.0-74-generic`:

Tags: nvidia

I tried to install NVIDIA
using

```
 sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.80.02.run
```

i got

[image]

```
The major and minor number of the compiler used to
compile the kernel:

gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)

YMLINK /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/450.80.02/build/nvidia/nv-kernel.o
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/450.80.02/build/Kbuild:196: recipe for target 'cc_version_check' failed
```

Comment: Myabe you are missing gcc compilers. Try this first `sudo apt install build-essential`. Also Try `bash` instead of `sh`.

Comment: Beside Karlom comment, confirm if DKMS is installed too: `sudo apt install dkms` then try again with the driver installation.

Comment: i tried to reinstall gcc and problem fixed